# Notepad++ Regex syntax for indefinite number of characters between two other characters

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am attempting to learn Regex syntax for use in Notepad++ but I have hit a snag.  I need to use the Find/Replace feature to remove a variety of characters from a given block of text and replace them (as a group) with one of these: |

My difficulty is in determining the syntactic construction for specifying the starting and ending characters of the items I want to delete while also allowing any unspecified number of characters between them to be deleted too.  The characters can be alphanumeric or nonalphanumeric (e.g. ">").

Here are examples of what I want to replace:

$uadr_ewgh_ksiyer:_

*$addr_abcr:4c_

$plbgtac_tgcvaxd:31_

$id:3_

$scxzatej:u $loihbv:u, $lgftvcu:u 5, 8734 $de 7:22 KL_

$(14836)_

Please note: Those samples also originally contained angled brackets "< >" which will have to be deleted too, but the site seems to think they are being used here as brackets to surround some kind of code. Will Notepad++ accept them as characters to be replaced or do they serve some special function in the syntax that prevents them being specified as a target for removal?

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: For each example input, could you say what the desired output is?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are replacing everything between the first dollar sign and last underscore, 
You could find `\$.*_` and replace with `|` or `$|_`.